# Cargar Imagenes seleccionadas de la galeria a un gridview

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, android-imageview, rutas

Esta aplicacion consiste en abrir la galeria de fotos y seleccionar los que yo requiera y luego cargarlas a la gridview de la aplicacion,el problema está cuando selecciono las imágenes de la galería  no me cargan la imágenes en la gridview,creo que el error pueda estar al momento de extraer las rutas de las imágenes e instanciarlo en el adaptador por favor quisiera saber donde esta el problema.
Aca les dejo el codigo.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final int COD_SELECCIONA=1;

String[]paths = new String[]{};
ArrayList<String> imagesEncodedList;
GridView imagenesGrid;
Button btnFoto;
ArrayList<String> array;
FileInputStream in;
File file = null;

private GridView gridView;
private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

public MainActivity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagesEncodedList =new ArrayList<>();

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.imagenesGrid);

    btnFoto= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFoto);


}
private void grid() {


gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this,paths);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

}
public void cargarImagen() {

    final CharSequence[] opciones={"Cargar Imagen","Cancelar"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertOpciones=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertOpciones.setTitle("Seleccione una Opción");
    alertOpciones.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                if (opciones[i].equals("Cargar Imagen")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    String[] extraMimeTypes = {"image/*", "video/*"};
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, extraMimeTypes);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);


                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), COD_SELECCIONA);
                }else{
                    dialogInterface.dismiss(); } }
    });
    alertOpciones.show();

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == COD_SELECCIONA && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
            if(clipData != null){
                for(int i=0; i<clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    paths = new String[]{getRealPathFromURI(uri)};
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    grid();
}
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            this,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    int column_index =
            cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnFoto:
            cargarImagen();

            break;
    } }}
```

---

<<<<<<<<<     Adaptador   >>>>>>>>

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private String[] filepath;


private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public GridViewAdapter(Activity a, String[] fpath) {
    activity = a;
    filepath = fpath;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return vi;
}}
```

---

<<<<<<<<<    Activity Main    >>>>>>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/imagenesGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

<<<<<<<<<   Activity Item Adaptador   >>>>>>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            card_view:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Donde pides los permisos para poder leer la memoria?, si no los tienes agregados  has uso de estos permisos (leer y escribir en la memoria)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Holas los permisos  estan presentes en el manifest

Comment: validas que los permisos fueron aceptados o denegados?

Comment: No hay problema con los permisos, mi duda es si los metodos empledos estan correctos o si he cometido un error en algún punto .